# Is there a version of the AD tools that provide the PowerShell output, similar to the Exchange tools?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, windows-server-2012

The Exchange administration tools output the exact PS commands they will (or just did) execute. Is there a different version of the AD tools (primarily AD Users & Computers) that have similar functionality? If not, is this an expected feature of Windows 8 Server?

Comment: If it's not here now, I suspect it's coming, as all the recent MS products do this. SCVMM, even SSMS has been doing this for years.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows Server 2012 AD DS comes with the **PowerShell**-based [**"Active Directory Administration Center"**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560631(v=ws.10)) user interface.

It includes a component called [Windows Powershell History Viewer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831702#windows_powershell_history_viewer), allowing you to review all the PowerShell cmdlets executed by the UI.

To use it for now, you'll need to promote a Windows Server 2008 R2 to Domain Controller and install ADWS ([Active Directory Web Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391908%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)) on it, as ADAC communicates with AD WS instead of an RPC Endpoint Mapper

Alternatively, use the [Active Directory Web Services Gateway](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2852) as proposed by @jscott

Comment: [This link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560652(v=ws.10\)) implies I can install the new ADAC tool on Windows 7: _Active Directory Administrative Center can be installed on computers running Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 or later._ Will it connect to a Windows 2008 AD forest?

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys You can install the [Active Directory Web Services Gateway](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2852) to use ADAC/PowerShell with 2003/2008 domains.